# How to recover a lost partition data?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Mistakenly, I lost a partition by disk initializing in Win10.

How can I recover it?

**The former:**

- sector size(logical/physical): 512B/4096B
- partition table: gpt
- start: 1049kb, end: 4001GB
- file system: ext4

**The latter:**

- sector size(logical/physical): i don't know it.
- partition table: gpt

  ```
  Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
     1              34          262177   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved part
  ```

Just the initializing was done.

Comment: Install `testdisk` in either Windows or Linux and run int on your disk. Ask any questions here if you are unsure what to do.

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [SU].

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't write anything to that partition, try [partition recovery](http://www.disk-partition.com/features/partition-recovery-wizard.html) in AOMEI Partition Assistant. I formatted my d drive once and get it back with this software.